# VSC putting in amount of spaces as level of indentation on newline

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation

I was just setting up visual studio code so that my python code uses tabs for indentation. Now when I press enter, instead of VSC putting in the correct amount of tabs to stay in the indent, it converts them to spaces. I have seen so many posts that deal with the opposite problem but not with this one. Has this happened to anyone?

example:

```py
    counter = 0
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        counter+=1
        if counter == 1:
            print(counter)
      #now when I pressed enter it added only two spaces instead of two tabs
```

My tab size is set to 4 and I have tried turning on/off the insert spaces setting, and Detect Indentation. Also I have tried clicking on the tab size in the right corner and using the menu there, but nothing has fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

1. You can choose to indent using spaces or tabs using the command pallete `Ctrl + Shift + P` or `⌘ + Shift + P` for mac.
2. Writing `indent`, gives the following options:
   [image: Indentation options from command pallete]
3. Choose `Convert Indentation Tabs`. This will fix the problem.

### Option 2

You can update the indentation for the VS Code by following these steps:

#### Select Spaces from bottom right

[image: Select spaces from bottom right]

#### Choose Indentation type

Choose whether you want to indent using space or tab (tab here).
[image: Select indentation type]

#### Choose tab size

The tab size is the number of columns (characters) tab will occupy. You can select that.
[image: Choose tab size]

Comment: Tried both, none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Open your settings.

[image]

1. Set the **Editor: Auto Indent** full

[image]

2.Set the **Editor: Tab Size** 4

[image]

Comment: The same as the comment before, tried them didn't work